# Clicking on logout button refreshing the page in php

Tags: php

I have created a page as index.php and added the code for login. It is working fine for me but when I click on logout button it is refreshing the page and if I am entering URL directly like `localhost/sample/testing.php` it's opening if I am not logged as well. User cannot access any page until he is logged in. Here is the code which I have Written. I have used static data to login because there is no database.

**Index.php**

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $userinfo = array(
            'user1'=>'password1',
            'user2'=>'password2'
            );
if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
  $_SESSION['username'] = '';
  header('Location:  ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}
if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
  if($userinfo[$_POST['username']] == $_POST['password']) {
      $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
      header("Location:  dashboard.php");
  }else {
     header("Location:  index.php");
  }
}
?>
```

**Sidebar.php**

```
<?php if($_SESSION['username']): ?>
<ul>
    <li class="dropdown profile_details_drop">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            <div class="profile_img">
                <div class="user-name">
                    <p><a href="?logout=1">Logout</p>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If any user is not logged in then also they are able to see the inner pages. They cannot see the page until they log in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, destroy the session when you log out. And redirect it to Login Page. Suppose index.php is the login page.

```
 if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
     session_start();
     session_destroy();
    header('Location: index.php');
 }
```

In the sidebar.php, check the session is set or not. If the session is not set means the user is not login. You can prevent them to access the page by redirecting them to login page

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 if (!isset($_SESSION["username"]))
{  
    header("location: index.php");
 } ?>
```

```html
<ul>
   <li class="dropdown profile_details_drop">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
         <div class="profile_img">
            <div class="user-name">
               <p>
      <a href="?logout=1">Logout</p>                                                                       
      </div>                                  
      <div class="clearfix"></div>    
      </div>  
      </a>                            
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have set `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`. thats why it is redirecting to same page. you need to change that for eg: `login.php`

```
if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['username']);// do not set it as empty, unset it
  //header('Location:  ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);//change this line to
 header('Location:  login.php');
}
```

and another error is in your else condition you are redirecting it to `index.php` which is why the non-logged in user able to see the index page.

```
else {
  //header("Location:  index.php");// change this to
  header('Location:  login.php');
}
```

> NOTE: I have added `login.php` only for eg. redirect the non-logged in user to where you want.

Comment: my index page itself where i have added login fucntionality code

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your code should me beautified.

Second of all, you have forget to close your `a href` tag, thus not your `$_GET` statement isset is true. Therefore, by clicking the link, the page is checking again for `if(isset($_POST['username']))` which is true, and you are redirected cause of your headers.

Consider of making a `logout.php` where you use `session_destroy` and `session_unset` and you redirect your users to `login.php`, for example:

logout.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_unset($_SESSION['username']);
session_unset();
session_destroy();
header('Location: login.php');
?>
```

Finally, consider of not using `$_GET`, but prefer `$_POST` or `$_SESSION` variables, only for the reason that are not visible on the URL.

Comment: but how can i restrict the pages to the users until unless they loggin

Comment: You will have to play with $_SESSION variables. If you do it this way, you can also implement mechanisms like CSRF tokens to prevent other known attacks. For example, when a user logs in, you will have to use `regenerate_session_id()` which will override the current session id was gained from login page. This way, only someone who has this id can visit your index file. Also, at logout, you unset the session and destroy it in order to remove this id.

Answer (score 0):

Unset the session variable in logout:

```
unset($_SESSION['username']);
```

Instead of assigning to empty string:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = '';
```